# Why does it not execute my func using apply_async? - multiprocessing python

Tags: python-multiprocessing, apply-async

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def function1(var1, var2):
    
    print("function1 executing")
    var3 = var1 + var2
    
    return var3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    pool = Pool()
    
    pool.apply_async(function1, args=(7, 5))
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I run this I don't get anything in the console. It shows:

In [1]:

In [2]:

I tryed it with several different functions but I don't get anything printed in the console. Sorry for the nooby question :DD

Comment: This works fine for me (Windows10, python3.10), and prints "function1 executing" as expected.

Comment: Damn, then it has to be some update or so... thanks a lot !

Comment: `apply_async` returns a promise (not really but it functions similarly). You need to explicitly wait for it to finish before joining the pool. So do `result = pool.apply_async(function1, args=(7, 5)); result.get()`